# Set Combo Box in Datagridview Column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView (dgvTable) with 2 columns. The first column contains combo boxes with preset data from a database. The second column is just text. 
I am trying to set the selection of the combo boxes in the first column based on the information in the second.

I simplified my code a bit to what I need help with:

```
string data = "MATCH THIS VARIABLE";
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTable.Rows)
{
    if (match.Equals(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString())) //checking to see if the second column value matches data
    {
        row.Cells[0].Value = "HELP";            //if the second column value == data then set the combobox selected value to "HELP"
    }
}
```

The combo boxes doesn't show the value

EDIT:
I started a new project and made a datagridview and added a columncombobox. I did set the value of the combobox successfully. The only difference is I am trying to change the datagridview combobox value in a separate window. Would that change anything?

Comment: You need to access the combobox control.
Might this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12265/How-to-add-other-controls-to-DataGrid-Part-I) help you

Comment: works fine for me, DataBound or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlName");
ddl.SelectedValue = "HELP";
```

Comment: I think op is asking for winforms DataGridview